# One Page checkout Submit Order redirects customer to empty shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9

Strange issue after migrating to a new server. Everything was working fine on the other server. Now new customers that get to one page checkout and fill out registration, choose shipping rate and payment method and then click submit order are being redirected to an empty shopping cart.

The order is placed in admin and the customer account is created, however the redirect issue and the fact that they cant login (they get invalid email or password). When they are redirected to empty shopping cart, they are also not logged in on the store. I assume this would be a server issue as we magento was behaving fine and we have not edited or added anything since the server change.